# HTML Doctype changed?

Tags: html, doctype, w3c

**Edit: My Problem was in the nginx.conf, I just added `include mime.types;` and now it works.**
I recently noticed that my css doesn't work when I put `<!DOCTYPE html>` on top of my Document, but when I `<!DOCTYPE>` it works. Isn't the first the 'official' way? Also w3c validator gives me errors on second but accepts first one. Tested with Firefox and Chromium under Linux. Has anbody else noticed this behaviour?

**My html**

```
!DOCTYPE>
<html>
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">    
        </head>
        <body>
```

**And my css**

```
table {
        border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: "Isn't the first the 'official' way? Also w3c validator gives me errors on second but accepts first one." That is correct. If your CSS only "works" with an invalid doctype, then the problem lies in your CSS.

Comment: Can you narrow down which CSS isn't working?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr no css is working with the correct Doctype tag, there's only this one border for the table, shouldn't be a css problem

Comment: ... so is your CSS working with or without the doctype?!

Comment: CSS works with `<!DOCTYPE>`  CSS doesn't work with `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: @danielr1996 - I tested on my end with both <!DOCTYPE html> and <!DOCTYPE> and both worked with an externally linked css file.  Chrome 42 / OSX.  Although <!DOCTYPE html> is the only correct method that you should be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<!DOCTYPE html>` is the only correct way to use HTML5.  You will need to provide code to troubleshoot further.